# Socket.io send binary data from client to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

With socket.io 1.0 it is now possible to send binary data from the server to the client side. For example, you can do this:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/assets/pigeon-final.png', function(err, buf){
     socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
     if(!err){
           console.log('image test success');
     }
});
```

Is it, however, possible to do the inverse? For example, sending binary data from the client side to the server side instead?

Answer (score 1):

From Socket IO documentation http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/

```
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost'); 
    socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'; 
    socket.send(new ArrayBuffer);
```

I hope i didn't missunderstand your question. Sorry if that is the case. Im not good at english...